# Getting undefined error for some JS after I activated Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, undefined

I'm getting an "undefined" error in this javascript after enabling Woocommerce in my Wordpress site.
Here is the code that has the error somewhere.....

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.clients .featured-thumbnail a').BlackAndWhite({
        hoverEffect : true, // default true
        // set the path to BnWWorker.js for a superfast implementation
        webworkerPath : false,
        // for the images with a fluid width and height 
        responsive:true,
        // to invert the hover effect
        invertHoverEffect: false,
        speed: { //this property could also be just speed: value for both fadeIn and fadeOut
            fadeIn: 200, // 200ms for fadeIn animations
            fadeOut: 800 // 800ms for fadeOut animations
        }
    });

    $(".latest_projects li:nth-child(4n), .skills li:nth-child(2n), .clients li:nth-child(4n)").addClass("nomargin");
});
```

Comment: Can you share more of where you're seeing the undefined? Is jQuery loaded? What about the `BlackAndWhite` plugin that you're using...is that loaded? Thanks.

Comment: Jquery is loaded. BlackAndWhite is not a plugin but is built-in to the Cherry Framework of my Wordpress theme. The error is actually thrown via a Chrome extension I use called JavaScript Errors Notifier 2.1.5

Comment: Can you share the error message?
And one note I found on the BlackAndWhite plugin repo was: _the script works only for the images hosted on the same server in which the page is loaded!_
Can you verify where the images are being hosted?

Comment: I am using Jetpack Photon as a CDN to serve up my images.

Comment: FIXED!! Based on the information from R.A. Lucas that the BlackAndWhite JS relies on where the images are being served up from I went ahead and commented out that JS file because I am serving up my images from a CDN. The error is gone now and the site works perfectly with no issues. Thanks sooooo much for the help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Verify where the images are being loaded from:

The BlackAndWhite plugin repo states that `the script works only for the images hosted on the same server in which the page is loaded!`